# How to make this regex negative?

Tags: java, regex

I would like to get the negative of this pattern

```java
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("FOR,FGS-(AX|AX2|AXMM|EMP|LV1|MLE)," + "(.*?)" + "FOR,");
```

I tried this but it did not work

```java
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^FOR,FGS-(AX|AX2|AXMM|EMP|LV1|MLE)," + "(.*?)" + "FOR,]");
```

I got this error with that:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>   Illegal character range near index 10
>   [^FOR,FGS-(AX|AX2|AXMM|EMP|LV1|MLE),(.*?)FOR,]
>             ^   at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)    at java.util.regex.Pattern.range(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)

Comment: That smybol only works for negating character sets, not arbitrary expressions. There is no simple way in regex to negate an expression.

Comment: Did you do any research? There are quite some duplicates dealing with this. For your question itself, you should add example inputs of things you want to match and things you do not want to match, else it is hard to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I just want to exclude a set of characters.

Comment: Please address all mentioned issues, thanks.

Comment: I need to get string which does not start with “FOR,FGS-“ followed by AX OR AX2 OR AXMM OR EMP OR LV1 OR MLE, and the end of the string must be FOR i hope it clear now thanks

Comment: Thats not a list of examples you want to match and a list of things you do not want to match. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe you wish to design an expression to exclude the listed strings, maybe an expression somewhat similar to:

```
^(?!.*(FOR,FGS-(AX|AX2|AXMM|EMP|LV1|MLE))).*$
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hei2Yr/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/hei2Yr/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(?!.*(FOR,FGS-(AX|AX2|AXMM|EMP|LV1|MLE))).*$";
final String string = "Anything before, FOR,FGS-AX, some other things FOR, anything you wish after\n"
     + "Anything before, FOR,FGS-AX2, some other things FOR, anything you wish after \n"
     + "Anything before, FOR,FGS-EMP, some other things FOR,  anything you wish after\n"
     + "Anything before, FOR,FGS-AX2, some other things FOR, anything you wish after \n"
     + "Anything before, FOR,FGS-AX2, some other things FOR, anything you wish after \n"
     + "Anything before, FOR,FGS-AXMM, some other things FOR, anything you wish after \n"
     + "Anything before, FOR,FGS-NOTAXMM, some other things FOR, anything you wish after ";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

#### Edit

Doing this task with a regular expression is rather complicated, If it would be a possibility, maybe you would try to split it in an array then check with a simple expression, exclude the undesired ones, and finally join the others.

String replace might be another option too, if possible.

---

These expressions can be look into also:

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/y0sNZH/1/)

#### [DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/Adupiw/1/)

Comment: thank you sooo much for your help, it is much appreciated

Comment: sorry, my English is too bad :), this is the example https://regex101.com/r/hei2Yr/6/,  the problem that I trying to design an expression to **exclude** the listed strings, what i do here in this example is **include** but that not right